# Github Actions with CUDA/cuFFT

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, cufft

I was wondering if anyone has had experienced getting CUDA/cuFFT to work with Github Actions CI.

I’m getting an error that cuFFtXt.h cannot be found: (Log can be found [here](https://github.com/arjunkunna/regent-fft-arjun/actions/runs/8382618687/job/22956716028))

This is despite installing CUDA and setting my path variables correctly, as seen below (I think, anyway): my test file can be found [here](https://github.com/arjunkunna/regent-fft-arjun/blob/main/test.sh):

```
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install -qq software-properties-common
wget -nv https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install -qq cuda-compiler-11.6


export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export CUDA=/usr/local/cuda

echo "CUDA_PATH=${CUDA_PATH}"
export PATH="$CUDA_PATH/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

My main.yml file can also be found [here](https://github.com/arjunkunna/regent-fft-arjun/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml#L16) in case it’s helpful.

Might anyone have any idea what I’m doing wrong? Any input would be much appreciated!

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

See above -- tried editing environment variables

Comment: You define an environment variable INCLUDE_PATH . You probably need to add the path to the CUFFT header to that variable (assuming your build system actually uses it). Your project is an impenetrably complex mixture of shell, python, lua and who knows what else and I think it is unreasonable to expect someone to debug it here